# Recording sound on an iPhone

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, recording, hardware, production-audio

I need a colleague to do some recordings for voice-over publication and because of confinement I cannot give them my material, nor can they go to a studio. They have an iPhone 7 and recording on it inside a closet has noticeable background noise in the room tone.

Would recording with a microphone connected to the phone be sufficient to have quality acceptable for publication? How much better would the recording be if it's done on a computer instead of a phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source a USB based microphone for the iphone. There are many available. What is the difference between a computer and a smartphone? Size and usability. Other than that, they are one and the same.